# Berzerk Mondegreens or: What did he say?

Tags: arcade, berzerk

[Berzerk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berzerk_(video_game))

40 years ago my English was...even less good. I had no idea what the machine said (the brassen robot voice didn't make it any better). At least I now know that (I write everything phonetically as I remember) "Interminoller" is "Intruder Alert!" But it gets even sillier with post facto rationalizations like "Nummer Neun, du hast Glück, es geht!"§ (I think if you escaped to another part of the maze - I googled, probably that's "The humanoid must not escape") or "Nine! Nine! Number Nine!" (when clearing a level?).

Does anyone know the complete list of sentences used in Berzerk, and for which situations?

§ "Number Nine, you are lucky, this works!"

Comment: As wikipedia, "different versions of the game being translated into four different languages such as English, French, German, and Spanish", are you sure what you're hearing is English?

Comment: @pinckerman: I just found a German version: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uin-HiRaZ-E - it definitely was the English one.